# How to hide 'Adblock Plus' tab in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Recently I noticed AdBlock Plus (v1.11) has added a tab to Chrome DevTools.  How can this be hidden or disabled?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

It looks like an option has been added to disable the feature from the ABP options page (https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/3796) and will be available when the next version is released (likely v1.12).

For the impatient:

Someone describes manually modifying the extension to disable the feature here: https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=44378

```
- go into your chrome profile
- extensions folder
- go into ABP folder:
for stable ABP: cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb 
for dev build: ldcecbkkoecffmfljeihcmifjjdoepkn

- rename devtools.js
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

On newer version you need to go to 'Settings' >> 'Advanced' >> 'Show Adblock plus panel in developer tools'

[image]